# How to Convert a Date to UNIX Miliseconds at Midnight for Hubspot API

Tags: python, datetime, hubspot

I am trying to input data into the Hubspot API using Python.

I have dates in the format of %m%d%Y. I need to convert this to UNIX time in milliseconds. I have that part set, I believe, using the code below.

```
t = '09/02/2020'
t = datetime.strptime(t, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
ts = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").timetuple())
ts * 10000
ts = int(ts)
```

The end result for this example is

```
t= 2020-09-02T00:00:00.000000

ts = 1599019200
```

If I take the result of ts and put it into https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php it appears to convert to 09/02/2020 @ 4:00am (UTC)

However Hubspot says "Date properties will only store the date, and must be set to midnight UTC for the date you want."

Where I am lost is, I don't know how to set this up so that the result is always set to midnight UTC and I cannot find any examples that would help me do that.

Can anyone help explain how to do that?

Comment: ts * 10000  -- Did you mean ts = ts * 10000.    You can write it as  ts *= 10000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [`datetime.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) method which returns date in [*unixtime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) format, but if you'll take a look in docs of this method, you'll see:

> **Note:** There is no method to obtain the POSIX timestamp directly from a naive [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) instance representing UTC time. If your application uses this convention and your system timezone is not set to UTC, you can obtain the POSIX timestamp by supplying `tzinfo=timezone.utc`:
>
> `timestamp = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()`
>
> or by calculating the timestamp directly:
>
> `timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) / timedelta(seconds=1)`

So, following docs solutions are:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

t = "09/02/2020"
ts = datetime.strptime(t, "%m/%d/%Y").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
# OR
ts = (datetime.strptime(t, "%m/%d/%Y") - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```